# Custom Class UIView - not changed

Tags: swift, xcode

Why in the code below, text changes as value, but there is no change in UIVIew. How do I refresh the data in a custom class? The value changes but does not refresh in the view. I have no ideas anymore.

```
ViewController.swift:
let SB = StatusBar()
SB.update()


StatusBar.swift:
class StatusBar: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Status: UITextField!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
   
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()

    }
    
    func update() {

        Status.text = "ok"
        print(Status.text)
        print("status updated.")
    }

    func xibSetup() {

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth, UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
 
    }
    
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of:self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "StatusBar", bundle: bundle)

        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `text` variable and where is it declared? You are not changing `Status.text` in the code

Comment: Sorry, edited the post but it still doesn't solve my problem. Text doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `update()`. In `xibSetup()`, add `update()`